# exact command for storing in the oracle table

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g

This is for a website in C#,Visual Studio 2010.

I've created a form with many textboxes, a date picker, dropdownlist, etc.
I've created a table in sqlplus with the columns with necessary types(varchar, number, date).
When I click the submit button in my form, I want to store the data in the table I've created.

Just to make it simpler for you guys, assume I have 3 text boxes
(name(text), id, date(i've printed the date in the text box as string)).

When I click submit it should fill the table with these data.
Im struggling to get the OracleCommand to execute this.

```
cmd = new OracleCommand(______, con);
```

If there is any other way I can do this by manipulating the types also its welcome :)

Comment: what is the input string you are using for the oracle command?

Comment: which input string?sry didn get u

Comment: that's what im asking.assume the 3 columns have (varchar,number,date).i need the exact INSERT query

Comment: how would you writhe the insert in sql plus.  that's what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert syntax for oracle commands generally follows the pattern;

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES (SOME_COLUMN_1 = :SomeParam1,SOME_COLUMN_2 = :SomeParam2 )";
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
command.Parameters.Add(":SomeParam1", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Your Val 1";
command.Parameters.Add(":SomeParam2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Your Val 2";
connection.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

See more reference examples here;
[Using Named Parameters with Oracle ODP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208176/Gotcha-sharp1161-Using-Named-Parameters-with-Oracl)